# Eclipse の動作が重い

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse の windows 64 bit ultimate version をインストールしたのですが、タブを切り替えるだけで（応答なし）と停まるくらい動作が重いです。原因が分かりません。

-- PC のスペック --
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700 CPU 3.00GHz
RAM: 16 GB
回線も問題ありません

Comment: Eclipseのバグの可能性が高いように思います。古いバージョンのEclipseを使用していませんか？

Comment: eclipse.iniファイルの設定値で、-Xmsと-Xmxの値はどうなっているでしょうか？